# Notification icon text background has changed

Tags: samsung

If you see the image for ex the wifi name's background has changed to white. I might have unknowingly changed something, but I don't know how to change it back. This problem is there for other situation also. If you see second image you can get an idea.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting is called **"Show button shapes"** and you can turn it off from the "Settings > Accessibility > Visibility enhancements" menu.